# TestFlight with Apple,no app review process?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

We would like to put our app on 1 iOS device, that is not a member of our developer program. Since Apple bought `TestFlight`, we could see on the docs that you must go through a review process . We dont want that. We only need to quickly check it on one device. 
Is there a way to do that, **without** connecting to that device physically ? (we are not in the same country)

Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, if this workaround will work for you and honestly its not the cleanest one. But  it did for me, Without going to TestFlight Ridiculous review process.

Ideally, in itunes connect, you should create internal users with technical roles assign to them, and share that apple ID for testing with real persons geographically any where.

But if you can't create new internal testers, which seems to be your situation, then What you can do is to share one time credentials of the "Apple ID of any internal tester aka users who have technical roles assign to them" and who have access to that latest build. 
Then the person in different country, he/she can sign in with these credentials of apple Id by going to Settings> Itunes & App Store and by signing off his existing apple id on that phone.

After this, basically his phone, will have access to all the latest build in TestFlight App for that Apple ID of internal tester and then after installing the app built that person want, he/she can sign off from that apple ID going back to original Apple ID under Settings itunes & apps store settings, and keep this newly installed app built on this phone.

If you concerned about sharing apple id credentials (password, email) of internal tester with this person, then you can temporary update them and then after following this process (huge pain in neck process) change them back.

Hope other stack flow users have better options.